# Use alias at HP-UX (Unix) with quote or special characters

Tags: shell, alias, hp-ux

At HP-UX I am trying to do the below:

```
$ alias awkFirst="awk -F',' '{print $1}'"
```

But this is not successful and returns:
*ksh: 1: parameter not set*

I don't understand what ksh has to do with it.

Also, I tried to declare the above alias inside script (which starts with the *#!/bin/sh*) but this is still failing with same error response for ksh.

Comment: I think I found the solution: $  alias awkFirst="awk -F'\,' '{print \$1}'"

Comment: Again, hardly could anybody help if you do not include some tags like `shell`.